# Redis HINCRBY hash field -1 counter for decrementing only till 0 or non negative value

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

Counts in negative: 
redis.hincrby(`User:${targetUser.id}`, "followerCount", -1)

I want it to stop at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINCRBY operation returns the new value after the increment operation.

```
redis> HSET myhash field 5
(integer) 1
redis> HINCRBY myhash field 1
(integer) 6
redis> HINCRBY myhash field -1
(integer) 5
```

If your HINCRBY operation returns -1, that means the followerCount for this user was 0, and hence should not be decreased.
So, you can fire a HSET to 0 to set it to zero.
A better approach would be to have an redis [transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) which will:

- first check the value using HGET,
- if it is more than zero, then do a HINCRBY with -1 increment
- if it is zero, do nothing.